# How to circumvent "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time" in a performant way for agent based simulation?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I would like to implement an agent-based simulation in Rust, but I run into the borrow checker.

Agents should live in a mutable grid, carrying a state in each cell.
Each agent carries some mutable state.
Usually, I would implement a collection of agents, e.g. as a `HashMap` from grid position to agent.
In a simulation step, I would iterate over all agents and then update the agent's state in dependence on its own state, the state of the grid at this position, and the state of other agents close by.

A made-up example could look something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Agent { // each agent carries some state
    id: i64,
    state: i32,
}

struct CellState { // some state of a grid cell
    state: i64,
}

struct Chart {
    agents: HashMap<usize, Agent>,
    grid: Vec<CellState>,
}

impl Chart {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Chart {
        let mut agents = HashMap::new(); // generate hash and populate with 2 agents
        agents.insert(10, Agent { id: 1, state: 1 });
        agents.insert(11, Agent { id: 2, state: 0 });
        let mut grid: Vec<CellState> = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        Chart {
            agents: agents,
            grid: grid,
        }
    }

    fn do_stuff(&mut self, agent: &mut Agent) {
        // here we want to update the state of agent,
        // based on the state of other agents in the grid
    }

    fn step_agents(&mut self) {
        for (_, agent) in &mut self.agents {
            self.do_stuff(agent);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ch = Chart::new(128);
    ch.step_agents();
}
```

This code produces the error

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:37:13
   |
36 |         for (_, agent) in &mut self.agents {
   |                           ----------------
   |                           |
   |                           first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                           first borrow later used here
37 |             self.do_stuff(agent);
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand the error and why the Rust compiler has a problem. What I do not understand is how to circumvent this problem in a performant way.

If I immutably borrow a reference to the agent, I cannot update its state. In a real example an agent would carry quite some state so cloning would not be cheap.

What would be the idiomatic Rust way to implement this?

Comment: if you can guarantee  you won't violate reference rules of rust in `do_stuff` you can use `RefCell`

Comment: Note that if this code worked, its behavior would be very sensitive to the iteration order of `self.values`, because agent A might use agent B's "old" value while agent B uses agent A's "new" value, so the agents can never actually agree about the state of the grid. If you are doing something like a cellular automaton, where the "agents" are synchronized to a global clock, you can't implement it this way (in Rust or any other language). If the agents are asynchronous, interior mutability should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for hints.
I am aware of the iteration order issues. In my problem this is no problem, as I have a second grid where changes during one time step are stored to ensure synchronization (I took this out from my example to keep the code short).
But, if I may ask, what would be your preferred way to synchronize agents?

Comment: If you build up a list of changes to the grid during the calculation phase and then apply them synchronously, you ought to be able to just use `&` references during the first phase and then during the apply phase you only have one reference anyway, so you can just make it `&mut`, no interior mutability. But it may depend on exactly what it is you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple exclusive references, in this case to the same `HashMap`, does indeed violate the constraints of the borrow checker.

Given that `Agent` apparently is not cheap to copy, I think you might want to look into wrapping `Agent` with [`std::cell::RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to dynamically borrow the values.

Here's a quick example:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Agent {
    id: i64,
    state: i32,
}

struct CellState {
    state: i64,
}

struct Chart {
    agents: HashMap<usize, RefCell<Agent>>,
    grid: Vec<CellState>,
}

impl Chart {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        let mut agents = HashMap::new();
        agents.insert(1, RefCell::new(Agent { id: 1, state: 0 }));
        agents.insert(2, RefCell::new(Agent { id: 2, state: 1 }));

        let mut grid: Vec<CellState> = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        Self { agents, grid }
    }

    fn do_stuff(&self, agent: &RefCell<Agent>) {
        for other in self.agents.values().filter(|&other| agent != other) {
            if other.borrow().state == 1 {
                agent.borrow_mut().state += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fn step_agents(&self) {
        for agent in self.agents.values() {
            self.do_stuff(agent);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut chart = Chart::new(128);
    chart.step_agents();
    
    for agent in chart.agents.values() {
        println!("{:?}", agent);
    }
}
```

As the `HashMap` is visited in arbitrary order, the above *could* then return:

```
RefCell { value: Agent { id: 1, state: 1 } }
RefCell { value: Agent { id: 2, state: 1 } }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I was not aware that RefCell can do the trick (thought that if just would shift the problem from compiler to run-time.
Thanks also for the small improvements in my code (will help me to get better in coding Rust)

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad to hear that it it solved your problem @Bernd Have a great week